# Convert Date in YYYYMM to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame in the format of:

```
["201301",1111],["201302",1111],["201702",2222],["201603",3333].
```

When I try to plot it using ggplot, there is a huge gap between years. I think the problem is caused by x value is consider as number.
[image]

Is it possible to fix the issue without using other libries?

Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried in order to convert that text to a date?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to `paste` a day and then use `as.Date`

```
as.Date(paste0("201301", "01"), "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2013-01-01"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I want to apply it to the whole data frame. I tried: df$V1 <- as.Date(paste0(df$V1, "01"), "%Y%m%d") But, it doesn't work.

Comment: @chen What is the error message